# Elastic search combine phrase and substring query

Tags: elasticsearch

For input sentence:

```
quick brown fox
```

I need to get matching for quick brown (phrase match) but also to uic (regex match). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean query to combine [match phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) and [regexp query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html).

Adding a working example with index data, search query and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "title":"quick brown fox"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "quick brown"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "title": {
              "value": ".*uic.*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65777213",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.5753641,
        "_source": {
          "title": "quick brown fox"
        }
      }
    ]
```